# ComplexExpand over various imaginary parts?

Tags: complex, algebraic-manipulation

I have an equation

```
a=(c+ I d);
b=(e+ I f);
```

I want to solve

```
dd=(a C0 * b K C0)/(a C0 + b K C0);
```

both e and f are imaginary parts. But complex expands takes them as a real.

Even `ComplexExpand[dd,{d,f}]` gives very complicated expressions.

I need to make it as simple as possible, and only real and imaginary parts.

any suggestions?

Comment: @Nasser it's not numerical I have the exact same expressions. Thanks though!

Comment: You changed your code. You had `i` and now you made it `I`. I used your original code before you changed it. No need to down vote.

Comment: If the RHS of `a = (c + I d)` and `b = (e + I f);` are just the explicit representations of the complex numbers `a` and `b`, then `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` are all **real**. That is `Re[a]`, `Im[a]`, `Re[b]`, `Im[b]` are all **real**.

Answer (score 1):

```
ComplexExpand[dd, {d, f}] // Simplify

(* (C0 K (c - Im[d] + I Re[d]) (e - Im[f] + I Re[f]))/
    (c + e K - Im[d] - K Im[f] + I Re[d] + I K Re[f]) *)
```